# Neo4j & Java - how to sum all values of attributes?

Tags: java, database, neo4j, cypher

I've created a graph database. There are nodes, that are called `Vertex` and that have attributes: `attr1:<float-value>`, `attr2:<float-value>`, etc., and relationships, that are called `Padre` and that have the follow attributes `attr1:<float-value>`, `attr2:<float-value>`, etc. Now, I'm writing a Java program that, given two `Vertex`es (two ints that match to the id of the nodes), check if a path exists between them. If so, then calculates the sum of attributes of the path.

I've tried with this code:

```
public void res(Session session, int x, int y) {

    float z = 0F;
    boolean found = false;

    while (!found) {
        if (x == y) {
            StatementResult res = session.run("MATCH (N:Vertex) WHERE N.ID=" + x +" RETURN PROPERTIES(N)");
            Record record = res.next();

            for (String a: record.get("PROPERTIES(N)").keys()) {
                if(a.equals("ID") || a.equals("IdAlbero")) {
                    continue;
                }

                Value k = record.get("PROPERTIES(N)").get(a);
                z += k.asFloat();
            }

            found = true;
        } else {
            StatementResult res = session.run("MATCH (N:Vertex) WHERE N.ID=" + x +" RETURN PROPERTIES(N)");
            Record record = res.next();
            for (String a: record.get("PROPERTIES(N)").keys()) {
                if(a.equals("ID") || a.equals("IdAlbero")) {
                    continue;
                }

                Value k = record.get("PROPERTIES(N)").get(a);
                z += k.asFloat();
            }

            res = session.run("MATCH (N:Vertex),(M:Vertex), (N) - [R:Padre] ->(M) WHERE N.ID = " + x + " RETURN PROPERTIES(R)");
            record = res.next();

            for (String a: record.get("PROPERTIES(R)").keys()) {
                if (a.equals("ID") || a.equals("IdAlbero")) {
                    continue;
                }

                Value k = record.get("PROPERTIES(R)").get(a);
                z += k.asFloat();
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println(z);
}
```

Now, I've an error to the `z += k.asFloat()` statement.
This is the error:

> Exception in thread "main" org.neo4j.driver.v1.exceptions.value.Uncoercible: Cannot coerce FLOAT to Java String
>       at org.neo4j.driver.internal.value.ValueAdapter.asString(ValueAdapter.java:84)
>       at Neo4j.res(Neo4j.java:160)
>       at Connessione.connettiti(Connessione.java:27)
>       at Connessione.main(Connessione.java:35).

What can I do?

Comment: Are you sure the properties are stored as floats? It seems that at least one of the properties that you are trying to convert to floats is stored as a string. You can use the Eclipse/NetBeans/IntelliJ debugger to stop the execution on an exception and see which value it is. Alternatively, you can just println the name of the property (`a`) and see which property causes the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know much Java, but you can fit everything in one Cypher-query using the [filter](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/#functions-filter) and [reduce](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/#functions-reduce):

```
MATCH (N1:Vertex {id: 1})
OPTIONAL MATCH (N1)-[R:Padre]->(N2:Vertex {id:3})
WITH N1, FILTER(k in keys(N1) WHERE k<>'id' AND k<>'idAlbero') as kN1,
     N2, FILTER(k in keys(N2) WHERE k<>'id' AND k<>'idAlbero') as kN2
WITH N1, kN1, REDUCE(sum1=0.0, k in kN1 | sum1 + toFloat(N1[k])) as sum1,
     N2, kN2, REDUCE(sum2=0.0, k in kN2 | sum2 + toFloat(N2[k])) as sum2
WITH N1, kN1, CASE WHEN sum1 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE sum1 END as sum1,
     N2, kN2, CASE WHEN sum2 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE sum2 END as sum2,
     sum1 + toFloat(sum2) as total
RETURN N1, kN1, sum1,
       N2, kN2, sum2,
       sum1 + sum2 as total
```